# How to configure IIS7 Advanced Logging rollover by local time?

Tags: iis-7, localtime

How to configure IIS7 Advanced Logging rollover by local time?

In options I set daily schedule (see picture http://gyazo.com/05843b6e29d51f21ee7ed2d6aa4d5157). But IIS create new log file using UTC time, not local time.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced logging doesn't support that feature, the following page documents that the filename is always in UTC format:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791730%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

I don't know if it's useful for you but normal and advanced logging can be enabled at the same time. For regular IIS logging you have the "Use local time for file naming and rollover" option available.

Otherwise the only option I can think of would be to log hourly and write a scheduled script to read the files and convert the filenames and data to local time.